# SQL Grouping based on Multiple Validity Entries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table, let's call it `contracts`, with the following dummy entries:

| ID | Name | Hours | ValidFrom | ValidUntil | ContractFrom | ContractUntil |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 15 | 01.01.2022 | 31.12.2022 | 01.01.2022 |  |
| 2 | John | 30 | 01.01.2023 | 31.12.9999 | 01.01.2022 |  |
| 3 | Jeff | 8 | 01.01.2023 | 31.12.9999 | 01.01.2022 |  |
| 4 | Tim | 10 | 01.01.2022 | 31.12.2023 | 01.01.2022 | 31.12.2022 |

Result

| Hours | ValidFrom | ValidUntil |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | 01.01.2022 | 31.12.2022 |
| 48 | 01.01.2023 | 31.12.2023 |

This is very simplified view of a legacy system. The real table contains much more cols. I need to find out how many contracted hours we had in a given time period. 31.12.9999 means the contract is valid until further notice.

The answer should work for PostgreSQL
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why have you tagged three different products?

Comment: *"The answer should work for SQL Server Thank you for your help."* Then why tag PostgreSQL and MySQL as well? Must the query *not* work on those data engines?

Comment: sorry updated the tagging

Comment: So the query should work for SQL Server, but you want to run it on PostgreSQL? Sounds like a terrible idea.

Comment: and the text ;)

Comment: How do you get the expected result of 48 hours? The 10 hours of Tim could (partly) be obtained in 2022 and then shouldn't count at this position?